# .htaccess in symfony2 web folder hides the whole folder

Tags: apache, symfony

I recently installed symfony2 its running on xampp the .htaccess in the /symfony/web folder hides the whole web folder and return a 500 error . i tried deleting the .htaccess in symfony web folder then it shows the folder back in the browser.  can you please help me with this please

Comment: Where have you pointed the document root for xampp? What apache error logs show when the `.htaccess` file is placed? To be sure you're using the correct file, what are the contents of the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: try /symfony/web/app_dev.php